# MVC C# Saving a list to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm saving properties in my database with the CreateAMeeting method. When I check the database I can see all properties saved except my list, I can't see my list properties in my database. I have been googling but I can't find if it's possible to see them or if I'm just not saving them properly. If I use a breakpoint I can see that the meeting(db.Meetings.Add(meeting);) model have the times i added in the Times list.

When I later try to retrieve my list in the ChooseTimes method, it's null. I don't know if the problem is that I'm saving it wrong or its something else. What am I doing wrong and is it possible to see saved lists in the database?

I'm not done with the fooreachloop, pay no attention to it.

```
public class MeetingController : BaseController
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public static Meeting NewMeeting;
    public static List<DateTime> TempTimes = new List<DateTime>();

    public ActionResult CreateMeeting()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult CreateAMeeting(Meeting meeting)
    {
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).SingleOrDefault();
        var model = new MeetingPeopleViewModel();

        meeting.Creator = user;
        meeting.Invited.Add(user);
        meeting.Times = TempTimes;
        meeting.Start = DateTime.Now;
        meeting.End = meeting.Start.AddMinutes(meeting.Minutes);
        db.Meetings.Add(meeting);
        db.SaveChanges();


        return View("AddToMeeting", model);
    }

    public ActionResult AddTempTime(DateTime Start, Meeting meeting)
    {
        TempTimes.Add(Start);
        meeting.Times = TempTimes;
        return View("CreateMeeting", meeting);
    }

    public ActionResult ChooseTimes()
    {
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).SingleOrDefault();
        Meeting meeting = new Meeting();

        foreach(var item in db.Meetings)
        {
            if(item.Invited.Contains(user))
            {
                meeting = item;
            }
        }
        return View(meeting);
    }
```

This is my Meeting model.

```
    public class Meeting
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Creator { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Invited { get; set; }
    public double Minutes { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DateTime> Times { get; set; }
    public bool AllDay { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> User { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser UserNotis { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Whats your meeting model? is it list?

Comment: It's an ICollection. I just added the model to my post. @UbiquitousDevelopers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to save my entire list in one field, wich obviusly isn't possible. So i had to create a new model with a database to save evrything in my list. Here is my save method if anyone else is having problems saving items in a list.

```
    public void SaveTimes(Meeting meeting)
    {
        foreach (var time in TempStart)
        {
            var mt = new MeetingTimes
            {
                MeetingId = meeting.Id,
                Meeting = meeting,
                Time = time
            };
            db.MeetingTimes.Add(mt);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as Im aware you can not save a literal list to a database, you can save all the items in a list to a database, by iterating through the list and saving each unique record.

```
public class MeetingController : BaseController
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public static Meeting NewMeeting;
    public static List<DateTime> TempTimes = new List<DateTime>();

    public ActionResult CreateMeeting()
    {
       return View();
    }

public ActionResult CreateAMeeting(Meeting meeting)
{
    var userName = User.Identity.Name;
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
    var model = new MeetingPeopleViewModel();

    meeting.Creator = user;
    meeting.Invited.Add(user);
    meeting.Times = TempTimes;
    meeting.Start = DateTime.Now;
    meeting.End = meeting.Start.AddMinutes(meeting.Minutes);
    db.Meetings.Add(meeting);
    db.SaveChanges();


    return View("AddToMeeting", model);
}

public ActionResult AddTempTime(DateTime Start, Meeting meeting)
{
    TempTimes.Add(Start);
    meeting.Times = TempTimes;
    return View("CreateMeeting", meeting);
}

public ActionResult ChooseTimes()
{
    var userName = User.Identity.Name;
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName);
    Meeting meeting = new Meeting();

    List<Meeting> Meetings = db.Meetings.ToList();

    foreach (var item in Meetings)
    {
        if (item.Invited.Contains(user))
        {
            meeting = item;
        }
    }

    return View(meeting);
}
```

There are better ways to do multiple things you are trying to do, but this will solve your issue.

You have to create a list of the meetings populated from the database so it is an Enumerable at the time you iterate rather than an query able,